# How to get into the Nilfgaardian camp?

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I decided (on Iorveth's path) to take the easy path into the camp through the passage whose entrance can be found underneath the brothel. I came out at the river bank as expected, but now how do I get into the camp? When I try to use the door is says **Locked**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was at the door of the Kaedwenian camp, not the Nilfgaardian one.

When you first see the night sky again you can leave the cave/passage and stand on the river bank. The (Kaedwenian) camp will be to your left up the hill. However, don't just exit the passage. Instead turn right and walk further through the caves, killing off some critters. Once you exit next time you will also only be able to walk to your left but this time a cut scene will interrupt ...

This is how to get to the Nilfgaardian camp.

Seems there is a difference between **Locked** and **Key required**. The latter seems to imply that one can indeed get a key.